# Let $s\ne t$ , How can I find $Cov(N_t,N_s)$?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

Let $N_t$ be a poisson proces with intensity $\lambda>0$ , I want to show
$$\rho=\sqrt{\frac{\min\{s,t\}}{\max\{s,t\}}}$$
How Can I do it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- If $s<t$

$$\begin{align}
  & \mathbb{E}\left[ {{N}_{t}}{{N}_{s}} \right]=\mathbb{E}\left[ {{N}_{t}}({{N}_{t}}-{{N}_{s}})+N_{s}^{2} \right] \\ 
 & \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,=\mathbb{E}\left[ {{N}_{t}}({{N}_{t}}-{{N}_{s}}) \right]+\mathbb{E}\left[ {{N}_{t}}^{2} \right] \\ 
 & \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,=\mathbb{E}\left[ {{N}_{t}} \right]\mathbb{E}\left[ {{N}_{t}}-{{N}_{s}} \right]+\mathbb{E}\left[ {{N}_{t}}^{2} \right] \\ 
 & \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,={{\lambda }^{2}}s(t-s)+\lambda s+{{\lambda }^{2}}{{s}^{2}} \\ 
 & \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,={{\lambda }^{2}}st+\lambda s \\ 
\end{align}$$
therefor
$$\operatorname{Cov}({{N}_{t}},{{N}_{s}})=\mathbb{E}\left[ {{N}_{t}}{{N}_{s}} \right]-\mathbb{E}\left[ {{N}_{t}} \right]\mathbb{E}\left[ {{N}_{s}} \right]={{\lambda }^{2}}st+\lambda t-{{\lambda }^{2}}st=\lambda t$$

- Similarly, if $t<s$
  $$\operatorname{\operatorname{Cov}}({{N}_{t}},{{N}_{s}})=\lambda s$$
  We have
  $$\rho =\frac{\operatorname{Cov}({{N}_{t}},{{N}_{s}})}{\sqrt{\operatorname{Var}({{N}_{t}})\operatorname{Var}({{N}_{s}})}}=\frac{\lambda \min \{s,t\}}{\lambda \sqrt{st}}=\frac{\min \{s,t\}}{\sqrt{st}}$$
  in other words
  $$\rho =\left\{ \begin{align}
    & \frac{s}{\sqrt{st}}=\sqrt{\frac{s}{t}}\,\,\,\,,\,\,\,\,\,s<t \\ 
   & \frac{t}{\sqrt{st}}\,=\sqrt{\frac{t}{s}}\,\,\,\,\,,\,\,\,\,\,t<s \\ 
  \end{align} \right.$$
  finally
  $$\rho =\sqrt{\frac{\min \{s,t\}}{\max \{s,t\}}}$$

Comment: Why $E[N_t(N_t-N_s)]=E[N_t]E[N_t-N_s]?$

Comment: $N_t$ has independent and stationary increment. Please Check it: http://www.randomservices.org/random/processes/Increments.html